# Ruby on Rails: Filter list of records in model before returning it to controller?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, filter

Lets assume I have the following model:

```
class Computer < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

and I retrieve all computers in my controllers like this:

```
@computers = Computer.all
```

Now I add a feature to deactivate certain computers and filter the deactivated computer like this:

```
  class Computer < ActiveRecord::Base
      scope :not_deactivated, -> { where('deactivated IS NULL OR deactivated = ?', false) }

  end
```

and in my controllers:

```
@computers = Computer.all.not_deactivated
```

The issue with this method is that I have to add `not_deactivated` in all my controllers.

Is it possible to do this filter in the model so I don't have to touch the controllers?

Comment: I believe not. but you can do a before_action :not_deactivated line on top of your controller. Then put the not_deactivated method in private of controller.

Answer (score 1):

Easy and common thing to do in controller:

```
before_action :not_deactivated # , only [:index...]

private
def not_deactivated
@computers = Computer.where(your code) 
end
```

Since the controller handles the view you must initiate the object somehow anyway. By filtering like that you can achieve what you are trying to do now with the model filter.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by declaring `default_scope` to run this every time you make a call to your `Computer` model

```
class Computer < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { where('deactivated IS NULL OR deactivated = ?', false) }
end
```

So, when you run `Computer.all` the result you get is `Computer.where('deactivated IS NULL OR deactivated = ?', false)`